# SQL query generated by the JPA framework fails to execute

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, jpa

The following piece of code:

```
 public void edit(Routing routing) throws NonexistentEntityException, Exception {
    EntityManager em = null;
    try {
        em = getEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        routing = em.merge(routing);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        String msg = ex.getLocalizedMessage();
        if (msg == null || msg.length() == 0) {
            Long id = routing.getRoutingRuleId();
            if (findRouting(id) == null) {
                throw new NonexistentEntityException("The routing with id " + id + " no longer exists.");
            }
        }
        throw ex;
    }
```

results into the following error in the logs:

2015-04-30 18:14:04,619 ERROR [ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)' com.xxx.yyy.admin.bean.RoutingManagerBean - Cannot update routing rule; org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException:Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00972: identifier is too long

Error Code: 972

Call: SELECT t1.ROUTING_RULE_ID, t1.BUSINESS_UNIT, t1.COUNTRY_DESC, t1.DANGEROUS_GOODS, t1.DESTINATION_ADDRESS_LOCATION, t1.DESTINATION_ADDRESS_TYPE, t1.DESTINATION_COUNTRY_DESC, t1.DESTINATION_STATE_DESC, t1.INDUSTRY_DESC, t1.ITEM_TYPE, t1.ITEM_WEIGHT, t1.ORIGIN_ADDRESS_LOCATION, t1.ORIGIN_ADDRESS_TYPE, t1.ORIGIN_COUNTRY_DESC, t1.ORIGIN_STATE_DESC, t1.SERVICE_DESC, t1.SERVICE_SUBTYPE_DESC,t1.SERVICE_TYPE_DESC, t1.STATE_DESC, t1.SUBJECT_DESC, t1.DESTINATION_CD FROM WP_ROUTING_WP_ROUTING t0, WP_ROUTING t1 WHERE ((t0.Routing_ROUTING_RULE_ID = ?) AND (t1.ROUTING_RULE_ID = t0.routingDataList_ROUTING_RULE_ID))
        bind => [1 parameter bound]

Query: ReadAllQuery(name="routingDataList" referenceClass=Routing sql="SELECT t1.ROUTING_RULE_ID, t1.BUSINESS_UNIT, t1.COUNTRY_DESC, t1.DANGEROUS_GOODS, t1.DESTINATION_ADDRESS_LOCATION, t1.DESTINATION_ADDRESS_TYPE, t1.DESTINATION_COUNTRY_DESC, t1.DESTINATION_STATE_DESC, t1.INDUSTRY_DESC, t1.ITEM_TYPE, t1.ITEM_WEIGHT, t1.ORIGIN_ADDRESS_LOCATION, t1.ORIGIN_ADDRESS_TYPE, t1.ORIGIN_COUNTRY_DESC, t1.ORIGIN_STATE_DESC, t1.SERVICE_DESC, t1.SERVICE_SUBTYPE_DESC, t1.SERVICE_TYPE_DESC, t1.STATE_DESC, t1.SUBJECT_DESC, t1.DESTINATION_CD FROM WP_ROUTING_WP_ROUTING t0, WP_ROUTING t1 WHERE ((t0.Routing_ROUTING_RULE_ID = ?) AND (t1.ROUTING_RULE_ID = t0.routingDataList_ROUTING_RULE_ID))")

---

Following is the Routing entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "WP_ROUTING")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Routing.findAll", query = "SELECT rt FROM Routing rt"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Routing.findById", query = "SELECT rt FROM Routing rt    where (rt.routingRuleId = :ruleId)")})

public class Routing implements Serializable {

/**
 * Compare Routing Rules.
 */
public static final Comparator<Routing> COMPARE_BY_RULE = new CompareByRule();
public static final String DEFAULT_RULE_VALUE = "Any";

private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x9bc8875b3a917b08L;

@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "WP_ROUTING_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName = "WP_ROUTING_ID_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "WP_ROUTING_ID_GENERATOR")
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ROUTING_RULE_ID")
private Long routingRuleId;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SUBJECT_DESC")
private String subjectDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "COUNTRY_DESC")
private String countryDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "STATE_DESC")
private String stateDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SERVICE_DESC")
private String serviceDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SERVICE_TYPE_DESC")
private String serviceTypeDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "SERVICE_SUBTYPE_DESC")
private String serviceSubtypeDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "INDUSTRY_DESC")
private String industryDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ORIGIN_COUNTRY_DESC")
private String originCountryDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ORIGIN_STATE_DESC")
private String originStateDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DESTINATION_COUNTRY_DESC")
private String destinationCountryDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DESTINATION_STATE_DESC")
private String destinationStateDesc;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ORIGIN_ADDRESS_TYPE")
private String originAddressType;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DESTINATION_ADDRESS_TYPE")
private String destinationAddressType;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ORIGIN_ADDRESS_LOCATION")
private String originAddressLocation;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DESTINATION_ADDRESS_LOCATION")
private String destinationAddressLocation;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "DANGEROUS_GOODS")
private String dangerousGoods;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "BUSINESS_UNIT")
private String businessUnit;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ITEM_TYPE")
private String itemType;

@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "ITEM_WEIGHT")
private String itemWeight;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "DESTINATION_CD", referencedColumnName = "DESTINATION_CD")
private Destination destination;

public Routing() {
}

public Routing(Long ident) {
    this.routingRuleId = ident;
}

public Long getRoutingRuleId() {
    return routingRuleId;
}

public void setRoutingRuleId(Long ident) {
    this.routingRuleId = ident;
}

public String getSubjectDesc() {
    return subjectDesc;
}

public void setSubjectDesc(String subject) {
    this.subjectDesc = subject;
}

public String getCountryDesc() {
    return countryDesc;
}

public void setCountryDesc(String country) {
    this.countryDesc = country;
}

public String getStateDesc() {
    return stateDesc;
}

public void setStateDesc(String state) {
    this.stateDesc = state;
}

public String getServiceDesc() {
    return serviceDesc;
}

public void setServiceDesc(String service) {
    this.serviceDesc = service;
}

public String getServiceTypeDesc() {
    return serviceTypeDesc;
}

public void setServiceTypeDesc(String type) {
    this.serviceTypeDesc = type;
}

public String getServiceSubtypeDesc() {
    return serviceSubtypeDesc;
}

public void setServiceSubtypeDesc(String subtype) {
    this.serviceSubtypeDesc = subtype;
}

public String getIndustryDesc() {
    return industryDesc;
}

public void setIndustryDesc(String industry) {
    this.industryDesc = industry;
}

public String getOriginCountryDesc() {
    return originCountryDesc;
}

public void setOriginCountryDesc(String originCountryDesc) {
    this.originCountryDesc = originCountryDesc;
}

public String getOriginStateDesc() {
    return originStateDesc;
}

public void setOriginStateDesc(String originStateDesc) {
    this.originStateDesc = originStateDesc;
}

public String getDestinationCountryDesc() {
    return destinationCountryDesc;
}

public void setDestinationCountryDesc(String country) {
    this.destinationCountryDesc = country;
}

public String getDestinationStateDesc() {
    return destinationStateDesc;
}

public void setDestinationStateDesc(String state) {
    this.destinationStateDesc = state;
}

public String getOriginAddressType() {
    return originAddressType;
}

public void setOriginAddressType(String type) {
    this.originAddressType = type;
}

public String getDestinationAddressType() {
    return destinationAddressType;
}

public void setDestinationAddressType(String type) {
    this.destinationAddressType = type;
}

public String getOriginAddressLocation() {
    return originAddressLocation;
}

public void setOriginAddressLocation(String location) {
    this.originAddressLocation = location;
}

public String getDestinationAddressLocation() {
    return destinationAddressLocation;
}

public void setDestinationAddressLocation(String location) {
    this.destinationAddressLocation = location;
}

public String getDangerousGoods() {
    return dangerousGoods;
}

public void setDangerousGoods(String dangerous) {
    this.dangerousGoods = dangerous;
}

public String getBusinessUnit() {
    return businessUnit;
}

public void setBusinessUnit(String unit) {
    this.businessUnit = unit;
}

public String getItemType() {
    return itemType;
}

public void setItemType(String type) {
    this.itemType = type;
}

public String getItemWeight() {
    return itemWeight;
}

public void setItemWeight(String weight) {
    this.itemWeight = weight;
}

public Destination getDestination() {
    return destination;
}

public void setDestination(Destination code) {
    this.destination = code;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) {
        return true;

    } else if (other instanceof Routing) {
        final Routing that = (Routing) other;
        return new EqualsBuilder()
                .append(this.routingRuleId, that.routingRuleId)
                .isEquals();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return new HashCodeBuilder()
            .append(this.routingRuleId)
            .toHashCode();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return new ToStringBuilder(this)
            .append("routingRuleId", this.routingRuleId)
            .append("subjectDesc", this.subjectDesc)
            .append("countryDesc", this.countryDesc)
            .append("stateDesc", this.stateDesc)
            .append("serviceDesc", this.serviceDesc)
            .append("serviceTypeDesc", this.serviceTypeDesc)
            .append("serviceSubtypeDesc", this.serviceSubtypeDesc)
            .append("industryDesc", this.industryDesc)
            .append("originCountryDesc", this.originCountryDesc)
            .append("originStateDesc", this.originStateDesc)
            .append("destinationCountryDesc", this.destinationCountryDesc)
            .append("destinationStateDesc", this.destinationStateDesc)
            .append("originAddressType", this.originAddressType)
            .append("destinationAddressType", this.destinationAddressType)
            .append("originAddressLocation", this.originAddressLocation)
            .append("destinationAddressLocation", this.destinationAddressLocation)
            .append("dangerousGoods", this.dangerousGoods)
            .append("businessUnit", this.businessUnit)
            .append("itemType", this.itemType)
            .append("itemWeight", this.itemWeight)
            .append("destination", this.destination)
            .toString();
}

/**
 * Create a copy of a Routing object.
 *
 * @param req the Routing object to copy, may be null.
 * @return a new Routing object with all properties set the same as the req object, or null if req is null.
 */
public static Routing copyOf(Routing req) {
    if (req != null) {
        Routing result = new Routing(req.getRoutingRuleId());
        result.setSubjectDesc(req.getSubjectDesc());
        result.setCountryDesc(req.getCountryDesc());
        result.setStateDesc(req.getStateDesc());
        result.setServiceDesc(req.getServiceDesc());
        result.setServiceTypeDesc(req.getServiceTypeDesc());
        result.setServiceSubtypeDesc(req.getServiceSubtypeDesc());
        result.setIndustryDesc(req.getIndustryDesc());
        result.setOriginCountryDesc(req.getOriginCountryDesc());
        result.setOriginStateDesc(req.getOriginStateDesc());
        result.setDestinationCountryDesc(req.getDestinationCountryDesc());
        result.setDestinationStateDesc(req.getDestinationStateDesc());
        result.setOriginAddressType(req.getOriginAddressType());
        result.setDestinationAddressType(req.getDestinationAddressType());
        result.setOriginAddressLocation(req.getOriginAddressLocation());
        result.setDestinationAddressLocation(req.getDestinationAddressLocation());
        result.setDangerousGoods(req.getDangerousGoods());
        result.setBusinessUnit(req.getBusinessUnit());
        result.setItemType(req.getItemType());
        result.setItemWeight(req.getItemWeight());
        result.setDestination(req.getDestination());
        return result;
    }
    return null;
}

/**
 * Compare Routing Rules.
 */
private static final class CompareByRule implements Serializable, Comparator<Routing> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x5be0fa9fd1736d74L;
    private static final Comparator<String> COMPARE_ANY_FIRST = new CompareAnyFirst();

    @Override
    public int compare(Routing lhs, Routing rhs) {
        return new CompareToBuilder()
                .append(lhs.subjectDesc, rhs.subjectDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.countryDesc, rhs.countryDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.stateDesc, rhs.stateDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.serviceDesc, rhs.serviceDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.serviceTypeDesc, rhs.serviceTypeDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.serviceSubtypeDesc, rhs.serviceSubtypeDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.industryDesc, rhs.industryDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.originCountryDesc, rhs.originCountryDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.originStateDesc, rhs.originStateDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.destinationCountryDesc, rhs.destinationCountryDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.destinationStateDesc, rhs.destinationStateDesc, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.originAddressType, rhs.originAddressType, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.destinationAddressType, rhs.destinationAddressType, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.originAddressLocation, rhs.originAddressLocation, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.destinationAddressLocation, rhs.destinationAddressLocation, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.dangerousGoods, rhs.dangerousGoods, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.businessUnit, rhs.businessUnit, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.itemType, rhs.itemType, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.itemWeight, rhs.itemWeight, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .append(lhs.destination, rhs.destination, COMPARE_ANY_FIRST)
                .toComparison();
    }
}

/**
 * A case-insensitive String comparator that sorts the values null, blank, or "Any" before other values.
 */
private static final class CompareAnyFirst implements Serializable, Comparator<String> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0x96afd43da5aa3ba9L;
    private static final String FIRST_VALUE = "aaaaaaaa";

    @Override
    public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
        String left = (StringUtils.isBlank(lhs) || lhs.equalsIgnoreCase(DEFAULT_RULE_VALUE)) ? FIRST_VALUE : lhs;
        String right = (StringUtils.isBlank(rhs) || rhs.equalsIgnoreCase(DEFAULT_RULE_VALUE)) ? FIRST_VALUE : rhs;

        return left.compareToIgnoreCase(right);
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone help me resolve this issue please.
It seems that the sql query generarated by the JPA is not per expectation.
If i modify the query to correct the table name as "WP_ROUTING" and column name "ROUTING_RULE_ID" and execute it in sql developer it works fine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Given your column names (e.g. DESTINATION_ADDRESS_LOCATION), something like t1.DESTINATION_ADDRESS_LOCATION is too long for Oracle's limit of 30 characters, see http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00972_identifier_is_too_long.htm

Comment: DESTINATION_ADDRESS_LOCATION is of 28 characters only. Should that be a problem? This is only variable with maximum size in the class and it doesn't exceed the oracle's limit.

Comment: You're right about that column but "routingDataList_ROUTING_RULE_ID" is too long

Comment: Yes, Thank You. Issue is resolved now.